# Starting a daemon from PHP

Tags: php, daemon, zombie-process

For a website, I need to be able to start and stop a daemon process. What I am currently doing is

```
exec("sudo /etc/init.d/daemonToStart start");
```

The daemon process is started, but Apache/PHP hangs. Doing a `ps aux` revealed that `sudo` itself changed into a zombie process, effectively killing all further progress. Is this normal behavior when trying to start a daeomon from PHP?

And yes, Apache has the right to execute the `/etc/init.d/daemonToStart` command. I altered the /etc/sudoers file to allow it to do so. No, I have not allowed Apache to be able to execute any kind of command, just a limited few to allow the website to work.

Anyway, going back to my question, is there a way to allow PHP to start daemons in a way that no zombie process is created? I ask this because when I do the reverse, stopping an already started daemon, works just fine.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `start` argument?

Comment: True, I forgot to add that to the question. In my code, I do have it. But, I'll edit the question for completeness.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try appending `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` to the command.

So this:

```
exec("sudo /etc/init.d/daemonToStart > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

Just in case you want to know what it does/why:

- `> /dev/null` - redirect STDOUT to /dev/null (blackhole it, in other words)
- `2>&1` - redirect STDERR to STDOUT (blackhole it as well)
- `&` detach process and run in the background

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation, but because the output is blackholed, any code that should have been executed after the daemon has started, is onmitted aswell. I have to check if the process has started, but that code is never fired...

Comment: When you start a process using this method, it should output the PID of the process that was created. You can take this, and then (for example) execute `ps | grep $pidOfProcessYouJustStarted` to make sure it is running.

Comment: Actually, you could just execute `ps | grep /etc/init.d/daemonToStart` to do the same thing...

Comment: I know, I am already doing that. ;) It seemed that that code was never executed though, as my browser didn't present me with an alert with the result value I presented. But my logs show that the code is actually being run. So thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I agree with DaveRandom, you have to suppress every output (stdout and stderr). But no need to launch in another process with the ending '`&`': the exec() function can't check the return code anymore, and returns ok even if there is an error...

And I prefer to store outputs in a temporary file, instead of 'blackhole'it.
Working solution:

```
$temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'php');
exec('sudo /etc/init.d/daemonToStart >'.$temp.' 2>&1');
```

Just read file content after, and delete temporary file:

```
$output = explode("\n", file_get_contents($temp));
@unlink($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried starting a daemon from PHP, but I *have* tried running other shell commands, with much trouble. Here are a few things I have tried, in the past:

- As per DaveRandom's answer, append `/dev/null 2>&1 &` to the end of your command. This will redirect errors to standard output. You can then use this output to debug.
- Make sure your webserver's user's PATH contains all referenced binaries inside your daemon script. You can do this by calling `exec('echo $PATH; whoami;)`. This will tell you the user PHP is running under, and it's current PATH variable.